# Why are my materials decreasing?

Tags: the-riftbreaker

I've got a steady decline of both Carbonium and Ironium at the moment where not long I go I had increases.  I know some of my mines have run out, but I don't recall these materials being used for anything except construction.

What structures or other reasons would cause Carbonium and Ironium (and other resources?) to drain steadily over time?  I've been running around my base trying to find the culprit and with zero Carbonium it's getting hard to make any repairs.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Armory and Tower Ammo Factory both require Carbonium and Ironium for upkeep. They stop once full, but if you consume ammo in the mech suit or by firing towers you will see a small drain until ammo tops up again.

Comment: Indeed. The material consumption of towers is not to be underestimated. Especially when you rely on ammo-expensive towers like rocket or artillery.